# Why many local ports were opened in simple sql connection?

Tags: .net, connection, network-traffic

I have an application that simply opens an SqlConnection to a remote host. 
My code is something like this:

```
SqlConnection sc = new SqlConnection();
sc.ConnectionString = sConnectionString;
sc.Open();
```

I ran the application while my network monitoring tool is open. I noticed that there were 4 local ports opened that communicates with the 1433 port of the remote host. I am expecting that only 1 port will open. Why is this so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have permissions to see the open database connections in the remote database server, compare this to the tcp/ip connections open in the machine hosting the application.

If the number of connections open on the database server match with the corresponding tcp/ip connections, you can be sure that there are multiple simultaneous connections open, and debug this further.

In SQL Server 2008, execute `sp_who2` or open the Activity Monitor. You should be able to identify the connection sources from the results. In the application host use `netstat -n` or other network monitoring tool.

#### See Also

> [Too many connections to SQL 2005](https://serverfault.com/questions/57434/too-many-connections-to-sql-2005)

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that you haven't closed your sqlconnection and it has been opened continuously , try restarting the server and (try restarting your computer as well) . And use this code after you do your work. It happened to me before and this worked for me .

```
SqlConnection sc = new SqlConnection();
sc.ConnectionString = sConnectionString;
sc.Open();
// do you coding here 
// complete all the operations related to this connection 
//close the connection 
sc.Close();
```

Comment: I have closed the sqlconnection and I even disposed it

Comment: What i can suggest is, 
1. Throughout your project, look for any of the connections which have been opened and not closed. or check if there are any applications in your computer which are using the same port to connect to your remote computer
1.Port 1433 is one of the most vulnerable ports for worms and hackers, Once scan for any security issues on that particular port.